# _CastError Null check operator used on a null value flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Am a bit lost and been scratching my head for a couple of days, I am getting this error

> Null check operator used on a null value

On this piece of code

```
 percent = (scores[section] ?? 0 / totalPerSection[section]!) * 100;
```

the section inside here  `(scores[section] ?? 0` is throwing a null pointer, but the value has data on the code above. Here is a more detailed code

```
   num getSectionScore(int section) {
    log("getSectionScore($section) called");
    var data = scores[section] ?? 0;
    log("getSectionScoredata($data) called");
    return scores[section] ?? 0;
  }
  num getSectionPtsPoss(int section) {
    return totalPerSection[section]!;
  }
  String getPercentage(int section) {
    log("getPercentage($section) called");
    num percent = 0;
    try {
      percent = (scores[section] ?? 0 / totalPerSection[section]!) * 100;
    } on NoSuchMethodError catch (_) { }

    if (percent % 1 == 0.0) { // if number is an int, return it as is
      return percent.truncate().toString();
    } else if (percent % 10 == 0.0) {  // else if num comes out to an even tenth (ex 0.1), return with 1 decimal
      return percent.toStringAsFixed(1);
    } else {
      return percent.toStringAsFixed(2);
    }
  }
```

This the function am using to get the sections and scores. When I do a console log on this bit here

```
var data = scores[section] ?? 0;
        log("getSectionScoredata($data) called");
```

no null pointer is getting thrown, as when the `scores[section]` is found to be null, 0 is being passed. Why am I getting the error on this line `percent = (scores[section] ?? 0` and I am passing a default value if the section is found to be null .

Any help on what am doing wrong is appreciated.

Comment: can you include what those values are equals to, just print them and include them in your post

Comment: and the method where totalPerSection[section] got it's value.

Comment: totalPerSection[section]! is the reason of issue. totalPerSection[section] is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throw that error on the line

```
percent = (scores[section] ?? 0 / totalPerSection[section]!) * 100;
```

because `totalPerSection[section]!` instead of `scores[section] ?? 0` like you think

You should check `totalPerSection[section]` value, i'm pretty sure this is null

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong, this error is not thrown for this piece of code:

```
(scores[section] ?? 0
```

Instead, the error is relative to this code:

```
totalPerSection[section]!
```

Either `totalPerSection` is still `null` at the time you are using it, or you are trying to access an `index` of `totalPerSection` that does not exist (remember `index` starts at 0)

Answer (score 1):

i think this is the error: `totalPerSection[section]!`

Null check operator is this mark ":`!`.

`scores[section]` is nullable , and you already set `0` when its null,
but you miss `totalPerSection[section]` is also `nullable` value.

Workaroud:
Remvoe mark `!` from `totalPerSection[section], and pass default  value.

you aslo need to catch error when `0/0` if you set 0 as default value